# Event fired when using facebook registration plugin

Tags: facebook, registration, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-login

When user visits a page which have Facebook Registration Plugin and if he is not logged into facebook, he clicks on "Log in to prefill the form..". I want to know that how can I refresh the complete page when the user logs in. I just want to know that which event is fired when user logs in. An onlogin() event is fired when user logs in using fb login plugin. Or is there any other way to refresh the page because only the iframe is refreshed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my *excellent* example here of how to monitor a login event:

http://jsfiddle.net/dmcs/qrXkZ/2/